# How to write treemap with composite key in mapDB

Tags: mapdb

We have https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/TreeMap_Composite_Key.java example but is not working.
Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example is now fixed, you will need latest 2.0 snapshot or  2.0 beta7 (once it is released) to run this.

For 1.0 branch use this older example
https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/release-1.0/src/test/java/examples/TreeMap_Composite_Key.java

Comment: Can we get expected release latest 2.0 snapshot date? we are eagerly waiting for this.